# Seeking sf equivalent of QGIS Extract Vertices

Tags: r, vector, sf

If there is an equivalent function in the sf library for QGIS Vector Geometry tool Extract Vertices, what is it?

Essentially st_cast(), but would incorporate node/vertex  index, part, part index, distance, and angle as attribute information.

I don't think a reprex is necessary for this question.

Comment: `st_coordinates` ?

Comment: How comprehensive do you want to be? Does it have to work for points, lines, polygons and multi-points, multi-lines, and multi-polygons? What are the distance and angle attributes? `st_coordinates` will get you x,y and the various part indexes, but not anything else.

Comment: there's not even an angle/azimuth function in `methods(class = "sf")` in `sf` or `lwgeom`; I like `system("qgis_process qgis:extractvertices -- INPUT=polygons.gpkg OUTPUT=vertices.gpkg") `, you may build tempfiles. https://github.com/r-spatial/RQGIS3

Comment: Ended up using `qgisprocess` to run QGIS Extract Vertices from R. Hadn't been using the QGIS packages since `RQGIS3` stopped getting actively maintained. Highly recommend `qgisprocess`, wish I had come across it earlier, very easy to use.